# UINavigationbar tintcolor not changed in detailviewcontroller

Tags: ipad, ios7, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

When i am trying to change the navigation bar tintcolor in split view the masterviewcontroller's navigationbarcolor chenged but detailviewcontroller navigation bar color not chenged. here is my code :

```
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

i want to change the navigation bar color throughout the application in iOS7 by clicking on a button can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by:

```
yourDetailViewController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```